# Run application at start up with Yocto Dunfell

Tags: yocto, beagleboneblack, bitbake, openembedded

I have coded a toggle.c application in C that toggles on and off a GPIO of the BeagleBone Black board. Practically it causes an external LED to flash.

I wish to prepare a Yocto image which includes the executable binary of the application and it launches the application automatically when starting up, thus causing the LED to flash.

I have followed along the examples I found on the web. My Yocto image includes the compiled binary of the application inside /usr/bin. I can execute it from command line, all fine.

But my Yocto **generated image does not start the binary automatically**. LED does not flash when starting Yocto generated Linux Image.

My workflow was:

- create a new layer
- new layer has an automatically generated 'recipes-example' directory
- underneath 'recipes-example' there was a directory which I renamed to 'toggle'
- inside 'toggle' there is the recipe toggle_0.1.bb
- I created a new directory inside 'toggle' that called 'files' where I stored the toggle.c and toggle.service files

toggle.service file

```
[Unit]
Description= A start script from a toggle.c program

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/toggle

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

toggle_0.1.bb

```
DESCRIPTION = "This is a program to toggle GPIO  on/off at an interval of 1s"
PRIORITY = "optional"
SECTION = "examples"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"
SRC_URI = "file://toggle.c"
S = "${WORKDIR}"
do_compile() {
${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} toggle.c -o toggle
}
do_install() {
install -d ${D}${bindir}
install -m 0755 toggle ${D}${bindir}
}

inherit systemd
SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE = "enable"
SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "toggle.service"

SRC_URI_append = " file://toggle.service "
FILES_${PN} += "${systemd_unitdir}/system/toggle.service"

do_install_append() {
  install -d ${D}/${systemd_unitdir}/system
  install -m 064 ${WORKDIR}/toggle.service ${D}/${systemd_unitdir}/system
}
```

I tried the same thing with diferent kind of image recipes: core-image-minimal, core-image-base, core-image-full-cmdline. All the same. They do not hold the normal Linux files for executing apps at start-up like /etc/init.d/rc.local.

Please point me towards a solution that would work for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: systemd service has been a normal solution to this problem for years already: you'll just need to figure out what detail is going wrong (is the file installed in the correct place? can you start the service using systemctl? is there anything in system log?)  First I might check the file permissions though: `064` probably does not do what you wanted

Comment: I can not start the service using 'systemctl ' because the command does not exist yocto images I used (core-image-base, core-image-minimal, core-image-full-cmdline). Sorry for the beginner question,I am indeed starting out. Where can I find the system log? Thank you for the hint about the file permissions.

Comment: do you have DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " systemd" and maybe DISTRO_FEATURES_BACKFILL_CONSIDERED += "sysvinit" in your conf/local.conf? If systemd is installed on image, you should have access to systemctl, journalctl and you should use them to do further debugging (if necessary).

Comment: Adding following in local.conf should enable `systemctl` 
`DISTRO_FEATURES += " systemd "
DISTRO_FEATURES_BACKFILL_CONSIDERED += "sysvinit"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemd"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_initscripts = "systemd-compat-units" `

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution for my problem, but I sorted it out using the **update-rc.d class** , instead of **systemd**. For some reason, even though I added `systemd` to my image by modifying `conf/local.conf` with  `DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " systemd"` , still I had no access to `systemctl` commands for debugging within the Yocto Project image.

My working solution is:

```
DESCRIPTION = "This is a recipe to launch executable program out of toggle.c at start up."
PRIORITY = "optional"
SECTION = "examples"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"
SRC_URI = "file://toggle.c"
S = "${WORKDIR}"
do_compile() {
${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} toggle.c -o toggle
}
do_install() {
install -d ${D}${bindir}
install -m 755 toggle ${D}${bindir}
install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/init.d
install -m 755 toggle ${D}${sysconfdir}/init.d/toggle
}
 
inherit update-rc.d
 
INITSCRIPT_NAME="toggle"
INITSCRIPT_PARAMS= "defaults 10"
```

For more information about `update-rc.d`and services, I recommend checking https://www.jamescoyle.net/cheat-sheets/791-update-rc-d-cheat-sheet.

Comment: You also have to add `VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemd"` to local.conf for systemd to be used.